# Whats is right sequence of using git?

Tags: git, github

I have two branches: `develop`, `production`.

1. Firtsly, I pull latest changes from `develop` branch.
2. After I do changes with these files.
3. Then to make add/commit in current develop  branch
4. After switch on the brance `production` Then I do push to selected branch

Need I make `pull` when I change branches or I can just `push` changes from one branch to another?

Comment: You don't need to pull when you change branches, but not doing that risks that you might not have the latest changes which happened in that branch.  Also note that you never pushed your changes made to `develop`.  This may or may not be what you intended.  I would recommend reading a basic Git tutorial to get the feeling for how to use Git.

Comment: I recommend using `git fetch` often and `git pull` never (or almost never). See the "related questions" link, What is the difference between 'git pull' and 'git fetch'?, and learn that `git pull` starts by *running* `git fetch` (and then does a second step). Mentally—and then actually—splitting these up will give you a much better picture of what Git is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three branches in total. I presume you have three, not considering master as Develop branch.

```
1. Master
2. Develop
3. Production
```

**Step1:**

- you create a develop branch from master `git checkout -b d/developing_f1`

**Step2:**

- You work on develop branch make commits and then create a review to the peer from Develop branch, when your done with review you merge your commit to master or just push the branch to origin.

**git commands:**

```
git add -A "feature"
git commit -m "Developed f1"
git push origin d/developing_f1
```

**Step3:**

If you want to create a branch from Develop to production is not advisable. You merge your branch to master and pull the latest and greatest of master. Then create production branch.

Because you don't want to miss the other feature developed by others.

**Step4:**

- You can merge you branch or rebase your branch master is upto you.

**Merge commands**

```
git checkout master
git merge d/developing_f1
git push origin master
```

- After merging your branch to master, now master has the f1 feature.
- You need to do `git pull origin master`, it will have f2, f3 features developed by others and the create a production branch.
- Now your production branch has all f1, f2, f3.